# .then() javascript not working

Tags: javascript, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to sign in using the Skype web SDK. I took code for signing in from some tutorials. Here is the code:

```
$('#signin').click(function () {
        $('#signin').hide();
        log('Signing in...');
        //debugger;
        // and invoke its asynchronous "signIn" method
        client.signInManager.signIn({
            username: 'ridaiftikhar@hotmail.com',
            password: 'sdfafa2'
        }).then(function () {
            //log in worked!
            alert('Signed in');
            $('#loginbox').hide();
            $('#chatfunctions').show();
        }, function (error) {
            //Something went wrong.
            alert(error);
        });
});
```

My problem is that the first function in `then` is not working. If I give an illegal username it will show me the error message, but it never shows the "Signed In" alert even when I provide the correct credentials.

Comment: For me your code says `"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`

Comment: Do you tested the code with JQuery @Justinas ?

Comment: @Error404 you should point your comment to OP who asked this question.

Comment: @Error404 If OP example does not work, so I assume he is missing jQuery library included to project.

Comment: I don't get what is unexpected about "*If I give an illegal username it will show me the error message but never shows the Signed In alert*". First, how would you sign in with an illegal username, and second, the whole point of `then` is that it either calls the first callback (when successful) *or* the second callback (when failed), and never both.

Comment: @Justinas i tested the code with JQuery and everything else works fine, the code just won't go in this particular function with the 'signed in' alert. Btw i'm a 'she', not 'he'

Comment: @Bergi illegal username means if i write 'ridaiftikhar.com' instead of 'ridaiftikhar@hotmail.com', it goes to the second callback. But if I give the username with correct domain and everything it doesn't go to either of the callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet I see you are using a Hotmail account to sign in. The sign-in code you are trying to execute is that of the Skype Web SDK which targets Skype for Business (not Skype consumer). Please use a valid Skype for Business account in order to sign in.
One other thing to note: If you are using username+password based auth then your organization that has a Skype for Business deployment must support username+password based auth. If not, sign-in will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems **client.signInManager.signIn** is returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and currently browsers does not support promises natively, though you can use **promise polyfill** for this to work.

Comment: i tried using the tag
<script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-7.0.4.min.js"></script>
in my html file but it still won't work.

Comment: you have to use babel or some other transpiler to make it work

Comment: If browsers don't support promises natively then why is the second callback being called? Then my code also should not work in case of an error, but it does

Answer (score 0):

When only `username` and `password` parameters are given, the SDK tries to discover the URL of the appropriate server for this user by going to `lyncdiscover.hotmail.com` and `lyncdiscoverinternal.hotmail.com` (since the given username is `@hotmail.com`). Since neither of the domains exist, the SDK doesn't get a response and never resolves/rejects the returned promise object. As Sid has said, a proper S4B username is needed to sign in.

The SDK does return a promise object, but it's not the native Promise - the SDK has its own polyfill.

Comment: Thanks, but since your reply was a little late, I already found this  (the hard way). But thanks again :)